# How do you call a function with parameters in a php object stdClass?

Tags: php, laravel

```
    $test1 = [
        'greeting' => function($name) {
            return 'Hello ' . $name;
        },
    ];

    $test2 = (object) $test1;

    dump($test1['greeting']('Danny'));
    dump($test2->greeting('Danny'));
```

[First try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzjvi.png)

[Second Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a58LD.png)

[Third try fail :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kBUz.png)

Sorry if this has been asked before but I didn't know how to phrase it, or if anyone can point me in the correct direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

I am trying to put a variable inside $test2->greeting but it is not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a pair of parentheses:

```
$result = ($test2->greeting)('Danny');
```

or, with `dump`:

```
dump(($test2->greeting)('Danny'));
```

If you don't, PHP will always interpret it as a method call.